# How to solve error retrieving information from server[RPC:S-5:AEC-0]

Tags: android

I am trying to solve this error to reset phone and add my account in it. But this error occurs every time. Please help me to solve out this i face much of problem from last 10 days for add inappbilling one month subscription in my app please some link or some code for help me to solve out this